# HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST error while sending GET request with php

Tags: php, http, web, request

While I'm trying to send a `GET` request to an address with `php` I receive `HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST` message and I can't figure out why.

Here's my code:

```
function redirect($url)
{
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

    $components = parse_url($url);

    $port = $components["port"];
    $ip = $components["host"];
    $path = $components["path"];

    //create and connect socket with the parameters entered by the user
    //$sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);

    echo "Establishing connection to the given adress...\n";


    //Connection timeout limit is set to 10 seconds...
    if(!isset($port))
    {
        $port = 80;
    }
    $sock = fsockopen($ip, $port,$errno, $errstr, 10) or die("Unable to connect...");

    $request = "GET $path HTTP/1.1" . "\r\n\r\n";


    fwrite($sock, $request);

    while ($header = stream_get_line($sock, 1024, "\r\n")) {
        $response.= $header . "\n";
    }
    echo $response;
    $loc = "";

    if (preg_match("/Location:\'(.*)\\n/", $response, $results))
        $loc = $results[1];

    echo $loc;

}
```

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: can we see what `$path` looks like after `parse_url()`

Comment: Your code snippet seems to be incomplete. It is difficult to deduce what may be the problem. Please provide "how you access the code" alongwith more appropriate code.

Comment: `$path` is correct I checked it. For example for `http://listen.radionomy.com/35x80` it is `/35x80`

Comment: I only do this to call the function and it works with some URLs: `redirect($argv[1]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific problem I've found a solution. If you want to get the headers from the request that I sent in the question above, you can use php's `get_headers($url)` method. It retrieves the headers that I was looking for. I'm really new to protocols and web-services and also to php (1 or 1.5 weeks), therefore I may have asked a silly question and not have been specific enough. Anyways thank you very much for your answers.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

A GET request also contains a header wich include things like the useragent oder the encoding, you should have a look at what you need to send and what's optional

Comment: I tried the same code with `http://radio1190.colorado.edu:8000/high.mp3` and it printed the headers however with `http://listen.radionomy.com/35x80` it gives the error message

Comment: Some websites actually check if the provided useragent is correct so this was my first suggestion